# Xcode Build getting failed with "There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode"

Tags: ios, xcode, github-actions, xcodebuild

I was trying to setup CI-CD to automate the build process using GitHub Actions. Steps followed are as mentioned below.

1. Create Keychain
2. Add certificate to Keychain
3. Unlock Keychain
4. Check if certificate is added to keychain using command "security find-identity -p codesigning -v"
5. Copy Provisioning profile to /Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
6. Install Yarn, POD and check the Xcode version (Xcode 13.2.1) and Node version (v18.16.1).
7. Archiving the project using the command mentioned below

```
xcodebuild clean archive PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER=${IOS_APP_ID} -workspace $cur_dir/../ios/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace -scheme $IOS_SCHEME -configuration $IOS_CONFIGURATION -allowProvisioningUpdates -derivedDataPath $cur_dir/../ios/build -archivePath $cur_dir/../ios/build/Products/${PROJECT_NAME}.xcarchive
```

After running the script received below error during the Xcode Build Archive.

Logs after running the script

```
** CLEAN SUCCEEDED **

note: Using new build system
note: Planning
Analyze workspace
Create build description
Build description signature: ************
Build description path: /Users/runner/work/Company-Mobile/Company-Mobile/ios/build/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/Test_Managed/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/XCBuildData/59698834595ff3-desc.xcbuild

** ARCHIVE FAILED **

note: Build preparation complete
note: Building targets in dependency order
error: There are no accounts registered with Xcode. Add your developer account to Xcode (in target 'Company Test Managed' from project 'Company')
error: No profiles for 'com.company.us.dev.hello' were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'com.company.us.dev.hello'. (in target 'Company DEV Managed' from project 'Company')
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encountered this error though `fsatlane match` was successful still there was CI error like:  `There are no accounts registered with Xcode... No profile found...`

I have fixed that error by disabling `Automatically Manage Signing` option from `Xcode` in my local machine and select the correct provisions profile. Then push the change to github. Now, after running `fastlane match` in ci(github action) successfully there was no provision profile related error.

Change in Xcode looks like this:

[image: Change in Xcode]

Change in `project.pbxproj` file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: what change exactly did you push?

Comment: I pushed the changes related to signing in `project.pbxproj` file

Comment: so you're not really sure what change you committed to the repo (and I understand you keep all the ios project there) and if these are all the changes you really need

Comment: I have added an image in the answer, please check